# How do i remove approved spam comments by date?

Tags: comments

Need to remove 1000 spam comments within a data range without removing legit comments

Comment: are you familiar with databases?

Comment: Does any one know if Akismet works on comments submitted before you activate it? does it scan through old comments?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, WordPress does not provide any functions to select comments by date range, as far as I know. And although you could [`wp_delete_comment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_comment) in a loop, it would take unnecessarily long.

As the [WordPress database entity relationship diagram shows](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), comments are limited to being in the `wp_comments` table and the `wp_commentmeta` table, which is convenient.

Use the MySQL command line client or phpMyAdmin to issue queries directly. If you:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` LIMIT 1
```

...you'll see the structure of the comment data. `comment_date` and `comment_date_gmt` are the fields that you'll play [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) with. `comment_date` is the date of the comment offset by the timezone setting you set in Settings/General. `comment_date_gmt` is the UTC+0 time, the universal truth.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_date` BETWEEN '2010-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-15 00:00:00';
```

No need to explain. Once you've **backed up your database** (I really mean it, back it up, please, things can go wrong), you are free to:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_date` BETWEEN '2010-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-15 00:00:00';
```

Now, as the database structure shows us we'll be left with lingering metadata in the `wp_commentmeta` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_commentmeta` WHERE `comment_ID` NOT IN (SELECT `comment_ID` FROM `wp_comments`);
```

A subquery will take care of these. Once you feel comfortable, substitute `SELECT *` for `DELETE FROM`.

To schedule such cleanups, like "delete all comments that older than a year", you would couple these queries together with different flavours of [`wp_schedule_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) and the [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class to issue queries. To construct the date you would use the [date functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) offered by WordPress.